# Building a dictionary of words from multiple lists in python

Tags: python, dictionary, count, frequency

I have a list of dictionaries of 100 points as follows:

```
datapoint1 a:1 b:2 c:6
datapoint2 a:2 d:8 p:10
.....
datapoint100: c:9 d:1 z:12
```

I want to print a list to a file as follows:

```
           a b c d ...... z
datapoint1 1 2 6 0 ...... 0
datapoint2 2 0 0 8 ...... 0
.........
.........
datapoint100 0 0 9 1 ...... 12
```

Here to mention a,b,c...z are just for example the real number of words are not known beforehand, so the total number of words is not 26, it can be 1000/ 10000 and a, b, .... will be replaced with real words like 'my', 'hi', 'tote' ... etc.

I have been thinking of trying to do it as follows:

1. build a dictionary of words lets call it global dictionary
2. then build a list of dictionaries where each dictionary represents a data point
3. then trying to map the list of dictionaries to the  global dictionaries

But this method seems complicated in python. Is there any better way of doing it in python?

Comment: A [Pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#from-a-list-of-dicts) might be helpful.

Comment: If you have 10,000 words, how are you going to print 10,000 columns?  (This might sound picky, but since it seems that all you want to do is reformat to include all the columns for every datapoint, how you represent this is an important question, imho.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care much about the fiddly bits of column alignment, this isn't too bad:

```
datapoints = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 6},
              {'a': 2, 'd': 8, 'p': 10},
              {'c': 9, 'd': 1, 'z': 12}]

# get all the keys ever seen
keys = sorted(set.union(*(set(dp) for dp in datapoints)))

with open("outfile.txt", "wb") as fp:
    # write the header
    fp.write("{}\n".format(' '.join([" "] + keys)))
    # loop over each point, getting the values in order (or 0 if they're absent)
    for i, datapoint in enumerate(datapoints):
        out = '{} {}\n'.format(i, ' '.join(str(datapoint.get(k, 0)) for k in keys))
        fp.write(out)
```

produces

```
  a b c d p z
0 1 2 6 0 0 0
1 2 0 0 8 10 0
2 0 0 9 1 0 12
```

As mentioned in the comments, the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) solution is pretty nice too:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(datapoints).fillna(0).astype(int)
>>> df
   a  b  c  d   p   z
0  1  2  6  0   0   0
1  2  0  0  8  10   0
2  0  0  9  1   0  12
>>> df.to_csv("outfile_pd.csv", sep=" ")
>>> !cat outfile_pd.csv
 a b c d p z
0 1 2 6 0 0 0
1 2 0 0 8 10 0
2 0 0 9 1 0 12
```

If you really need the columns nicely aligned, then there are ways to do that too, but I never need them so I don't know much about them.

Comment: you can use `'col {0:5} | col {1:5}'.format(1, 2)` to make each column the same width (by adding spaces to the shorter than **{id:width}**).

Answer (score 0):

**Program:**

```
data_points = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 6},
    {'a': 2, 'd': 8, 'p': 10},
    {'c': 9, 'd': 1, 'z': 12},
    {'e': 3, 'f': 6, 'g': 3}
]

merged_data_points = {
}

for data_point in data_points:
    for k, v in data_point.items():
        if k not in merged_data_points:
            merged_data_points[k] = []
        merged_data_points[k].append(v)

# print the merged datapoints
print '{'
for k in merged_data_points:
    print '  {0}: {1},'.format(k, merged_data_points[k])
print '}'
```

**Output:**

```
{
  a: [1, 2],
  c: [6, 9],
  b: [2],
  e: [3],
  d: [8, 1],
  g: [3],
  f: [6],
  p: [10],
  z: [12],
}
```

Comment: I have another question. Is there a nicer way of removing a specific column from the printed data? For example: I have the above following printed output@ Morgan Wilde . I want to remove the column of 'c' and 'd' by its key values.

Comment: @tom10 you correctly pointed out the problem. I am having difficulties reading the 10000 column file. I want to feed this into another program and do some pre processing. I wrote the program in python to read this 4GB file and trying to preprocess so that I can reduce the number of columns. Any easy way of doing it?

Comment: In my solution, a 'column' in your output is just a key in the `merged_data_points` dictionary.  If you want to get rid of a column, just ignore that key in the dictionary.